# Sound outputs from front and rear jacks simultaneously - Debian Wheezy

Tags: audio, debian

I am unable to get debian to automatically mute the rear port when I put my headphones into the front ports.

I have already played with auto mute in alsamixer!

Comment: What audio chipset do you have?

Comment: Realtek ACL260 on HDA Intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was defiantly hardware based I installed a sound card and everything now works fine.

Issue was the same after reinstalling the mixer software, changing versions of debian and testing with ubuntu live.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. Try reinstlling the mixer software. You have to find the exact same software or it wont work

Comment: try this website, it got good rates http://www.auspisoft.com/r/realtek_acl260.html